# How to rename files to include the filepath?

Tags: python

Right now, my exam files are ordered like so:

[image]

Where y stands for the year and s stands for the subject. Within each subject folder are 3 files - t1.txt, t2.txt and t3.txt, representing 3 different tests for that subject in that year.

I'm trying to group all the subjects together in one folder, and this requires adding the year to the beginning of the file name, other wise there will be 9 files with the same name.

My code so far is:

```
import os

mypath = 'D:\\Queensland Academies\\IB Resources\\test'

for root, subdir, file in os.walk(mypath):
    for f in file:
        new = 'test' + f
        print(new)
        os.rename(os.path.join(mypath, f), os.path.join(mypath, new))
```

However, this returns:`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: my current goal is not to move any files but to simply rename them

Comment: why arent you printing out `os.path.join(mypath, f)` and see if the file is there when to error message clearly tells you that the file location you provided is not there?

Comment: @PatrickArtner sorry, I attached an earlier version. The same error occurs with mypath on both f and new

Comment: `f` is inside `subdir` - NOT in `mypath` - unless you copy it there first.

Comment: Read:  [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @PatrickArtner printing os.path.join(mypath, f) returns no error message and the file path + name shows up as expected

Comment: try printing  `print(os.path.join("C:\ThisDirectoryDoesNotExists\","neitherDoesThisFile.txt"))` - works as well.... because the error is thrown when you try to access a file thats not there inside `os.rename(path_to_file_that_does_not_exist, newname)`

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of mappings between original file and renamed file? I'm not sure if you want to move the test files to the year directories, or if you want to move the subject directories to the root directory.

Comment: @Pierre Sorry for the confusion. Right now I'm not trying to move anything but just to rename then. I.e. t1.txt in year 1 and subject 1 will become D:\y1\s1\t1.txt

Comment: Isn't `D:\y1\s1\t1.txt` what you already have? This corresponds exactly to your description: `Where y stands for the year and s stands for the subject. Within each subject folder are 3 files - t1.txt, t2.txt and t3.txt, representing 3 different tests for that subject in that year.`

Comment: @Pierre right now the file name is 't1.txt', but I wish to rename it to 'D:\y1\s1\t1.txt'

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

mypath = 'D:\\Queensland Academies\\IB Resources\\test'

for root, subdir, file in os.walk(mypath):
    for f in file:
        dirs = root.split("\\") [1:] # omit drive letter
        new = '_'.join(dirs) + '_' + f

        # print(new)
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, new))
```

gets the directory names from subdir omitting the drive letter and combines them with `'_'` and the original file name....

`'mypath'` is simply the starting path for os.walk() - it is not the location the file currently at hand is located at.

---

If I use this piece of code (replacing `os.rename` by `print`) I get for my `C:\temp\`:

```
c:\temp\a;b.txt           c:\temp\temp_a;b.txt
c:\temp\new 1.txt         c:\temp\temp_new 1.txt
c:\temp\new 2.txt         c:\temp\temp_new 2.txt
c:\temp\numbers.dat.txt   c:\temp\temp_numbers.dat.txt
c:\temp\tempfile.txt      c:\temp\temp_tempfile.txt
c:\temp\tempfile.txt.gz   c:\temp\temp_tempfile.txt.gz
c:\temp\tempfile.txt.gzip c:\temp\temp_tempfile.txt.gzip
```